# Efax-gtk using Trendnet TFM-561U modem

Tags: modem, fax

I am running Ubuntu 14.0.4 using and external modem.  It will not recognize the modem.  Is anyone familiar with modem and the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

1. First, plug in the fax modem to an available USB 2.0 port.
2. Open a terminal: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Run it:

   ```
   sudo -i
   apt-get install efax-gtk
   modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0572 product=0x1329
   dmesg | tail  -n 100
   ```

   You are looking for something similar to this:

   > usb 2-1: Product: USB Modem
   >   usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 35680336
   >   cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: **ttyACM0:** USB ACM device
   >   usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm

   You are interested in the serial address that Ubuntu has assigned to the USB fax modem. I’ve highlighted that information above in bold type.
4. The only thing you now have left to do is to plug in one end of a modular phone cord to the other end of the USB fax modem, and the other end of the modular phone cord into an available modular phone jack.
5. In `efax-gtk` select *File Settings* from the menus. On the second tab, you will need to enter the serial address that Ubuntu assigned to your fax modem when you set it up.

Source: http://efax-gtk.sourceforge.net/README

Comment: I have the efax-cgt installed and the modem is assigned to ttyACM0.  efax still will not send a fax.

Comment: If your fax didn’t send successfully, review the fax log file to help diagnose any problems you might be having. You will know if there are any errors when sending the fax, since they will show up as red text in the text area that’s in the lower half of the efax-gtk window. Since all errors – minor and major – show up in red text, you will need to check to see which ones are important enough to follow up on.