# Efax-gtk using Trendnet TFM-561U modem on 17.04

Tags: usb-modem, fax

[I'm trying to find the right AT commands to talk to a Trendnet TFM-561U modem on 17.04 and I am having no luck. If I take the default in `efax-gtk`, then this is what I get in log file:

```
efax-0.9a: 14:54:09 opened /dev/ttyACM0
efax-0.9a: 14:54:09 Warning: unexpected response "CONNECT"
efax-0.9a: 14:54:15 sync: dropping DTR
efax-0.9a: 14:54:17 Error: modem command (Z&FE&D2S7=120&C0) failed
efax-0.9a: 14:54:17 failed page /home/john/temp/faxfile.pdf.001
efax-0.9a: 14:54:23 Error: modem command (ATZ) failed
efax-0.9a: 14:54:23 finished - invalid modem response
```

I'd love to know the proper AT commands for this modem but I can't find it anywhere.
I am trying to run (i. e. send a fax) using `efax-gtk`. I connect the USB Trendnet TFM-561U modem on my 17.04 mate system. This modem came off a working Windows 7 system.  I read [Efax-gtk using Trendnet TFM-561U modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544807/efax-gtk-using-trendnet-tfm-561u-modem).

```
$ sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0572 product=0x1329
[  332.455588] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  335.025066] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0572, idProduct=1329
[  335.025070] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  335.025072] usb 1-2: Product: USB Modem
[  335.025075] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Conexant
[  335.025076] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 24680246
[  335.572080] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  335.572244] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  335.572244] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[  644.375732] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  644.375740] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  644.375745] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic

$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Sep  3 17:52 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I am a member of the `dialout` group.

Comment: Thanks for editing my posting. I couldn't even figure out what you did but it does look nice.

Comment: I am trying to run (i.e. send a fax) using efax-gtk. I connect the USB  Trendnet TFM-561U modem on my 17.04 mate system. This modem came off a working Windows 7 system.

Comment: Please note that your formatting scheme has me lost.

Comment: It turns out to be on-topic as the problem is efax-gtk doesn't send right commands to modem but efax works perfectly. Will open new question.